# What is the default color palette for the raster package in R?

Tags: r

How can I recreate the default color palette for the raster package in R? I cannot find details on the default raster plotting color scheme in online documentation. Thanks!

Comment: [The source](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/plot.R) line 12 shows `col <- rev(terrain.colors(255))`. If you load the library and type `terrain.colors` you will see the code used to calculate the colors.

Comment: Terrific. Thank you!!

Comment: one of you (@IanCampbell or OP) should post this comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we review [the source code](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/plot.R) for the custom plot method for objects of type `Raster`, we will see that line 12 shows:

```
col <- rev(terrain.colors(255))
```

If you type [`terrain.colors`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/grDevices/R/colorstuff.R) you will see the code used to calculate the colors:

```
terrain.colors
function (n, alpha = 1, rev = FALSE) 
{
    if ((n <- as.integer(n[1L])) > 0) {
        k <- n%/%2
        h <- c(4/12, 2/12, 0/12)
        s <- c(1, 1, 0)
        v <- c(0.65, 0.9, 0.95)
        cols <- c(hsv(h = seq.int(h[1L], h[2L], length.out = k), 
            s = seq.int(s[1L], s[2L], length.out = k), v = seq.int(v[1L], 
                v[2L], length.out = k), alpha = alpha), hsv(h = seq.int(h[2L], 
            h[3L], length.out = n - k + 1)[-1L], s = seq.int(s[2L], 
            s[3L], length.out = n - k + 1)[-1L], v = seq.int(v[2L], 
            v[3L], length.out = n - k + 1)[-1L], alpha = alpha))
        if (rev) 
            cols <- rev(cols)
        cols
    }
    else character()
}
```